# Update multiple rows in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net

I need to know to to update more than one rows in database using vb.net.
In my database it have 3 rows (have id for each other ) and on my vb.net I have 3 text boxes. I need to update data using those 3 text boxes in one shot.

here is my vb.net code

```vb
MysqlConn.Open()
Dim Query As String

Query = "update cs set subject=@subject, place=@place where=@id"
COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader

MessageBox.Show("Data Saved")
MysqlConn.Close()
```

Comment: so exactly how is this not working for you?

Comment: you need to provide the values for those parameters before it will do anything; you do not need to ExecuteReader, because that is not reading anything; given the WHERE clause, you will have to run it multiple times to update more than one row (assuming the ID is supposed to be unique).

Comment: so how can i run same query in multiple times ?

Comment: there have 3 rows ( id = 1, 2, 3 ) i need to update all rows under id 1,2,3 in same time not with same value..there have 3 text box to and i need to update my 3 rows using that 3 text box

Comment: Not certain about myssql, but in other RDBMS's, your query needs a column on the predicate also -- `"update cs set subject=@subject, place=@place where id = @id"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass parameters

```vb
Dim sql as String = "update cs set subject=@subject, place=@place where id=@id" ' NOTE: id = @id
cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, MysqlConn)
cmd.Parameters.addWithValue("@subject", txtSubject.Text)
cmd.Parameters.addWithValue("@place", txtPlace.Text)
cmd.Parameters.addWithValue("@id", CInt(txtId.Text)) ' id is int , I hope
' instead of reader do ExecuteNonQuery
Dim ret = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

MessageBox.Show("Success: " & (ret > 0).ToString())
```

You can also do `ExecuteReader` but you do that when you return something. I don't know `MySql` but in `Sql Server` you can use `Output` with `Insert` and `Update`. And you can use `ExecuteReader` to get this output.